# Is this correct? $f(z) = z ^2\bar{z}^3$, $f_z(z) = \ldots$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I would like to know if this derivative is right.

Let $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z) = z^2\bar{z}^3 = (x+iy)^2(x-iy)^3$. Then
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = 2 (x + iy) (x - iy)^3 + 3(x + iy)^2 (x - iy)^2,
$$
and
$$
\frac{df}{dy} = 2i(x + iy)(x - iy)^3 - 3i (x + iy)^2(x - iy)^2,
$$
hence
\begin{align}
f_z(z) = \frac{df}{dz} = \frac{f_x(z) - f_y(z)}{2} &= (1 - i)(x+iy)(x-iy)^3 + \tfrac{3}{2}(1 + i)(x + iy)^2 (x - iy)^2 \\
&= (1 - i)|z|^2\bar{z}^2 + \tfrac{3}{2} (1 + i)|z|^4.
\end{align}

Comment: You should rather use [Wirtinger derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives).

Comment: This function is not differentiable with respect to $z$ due to the presence of $\overline{z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an $i$ missing in your formula. The correct definition is $$\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

After you reconsider your formula you will get the right answer. Moreover, it is worth to note that, because the way $f_z$ is defined, the product rules applies (try to prove it, it is a nice exercise): $$(fg)_z=f_zg+fg_z$$

Also, if $f(z)=z$ and $h(z)=\overline{z}$ then $f_z=1$ and $g_z=0$, hence if $f$ is your function we get that $$f_z=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(z^2)\overline{z}^3+z^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\overline{z^3})=2z\overline{z}^3$$